# Integration tests CRUD Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing

I need to do integration tests for my Ember app, for example in the user template :

```
<div class="container">

<h1>{{model.firstName}} {{model.lastName}}</h1>
<p>Age: {{model.age}} years old</p>
<p>Job: {{model.job}}</p>
<img src="{{model.image}}" alt="img" id="image">


</div>
```

I have to test that the list of users is correctly displayed. Is it possible to do so ?

I have never done that and I'm kind of lost here. Would it be something like :

```
test('it renders all users', function(assert) {
this.set('users', [
{ firstName: 'Tubby'},
{ firstName: 'Spot'},
{ firstName: 'Chester'},
{ firstName: 'Frisky'}
]);

 this.render(hbs`{{user users=users}}`);
 assert.equal(this.$('.user').length, 4);
 });
```

Even though I read many articles about the integration tests, I still don't understand if it can be used for something that is not a component.

What about redirection ? Let's just say that I have to write an integration test that verifies that the redirection is okay. Can I do that with integration tests ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use an acceptance test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be worth doing a quick review of the testing options:

Unit tests allow us to test small chunks of code. Things that are easy to test this way would be services, serializers or adapters.

Integration tests are primarily designed to let you test components and the way they work together and interact with users. Things often tested include events of different sorts (clicks, keystrokes, etc) and the way a component reacts to different types of data.

Acceptance tests are often used for testing the integrated whole of your app (pretending to be your user and browsing the site).

Often, checks for redirects would either be an acceptance test. You could also do unit tests (if you have complicated route logic that handles various scenarios that redirect). Testing redirects in an integration test would primarily focus around making sure clicking a button would attempt to redirect somewhere else.

Does that help?

Comment: You bet! If you wouldn’t mind accepting the answer, I use acceptances as a way to find things folks still need help with here ...

Answer (score 0):

I hope, The below tutorial will help you to understand the test case. The tutorial has examples for all testing(UNIT, Acceptance and Integration).

https://medium.com/@srajas02/ember-test-case-for-a-crud-application-with-mirage-d6d9836bfee2

Source Code: https://github.com/srajas0/ember-test-cases